# Error in publishing data to cloud from device using MQTT and AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have a device that communicates with the cloud and publishes data. I am using MQTT protocol and certificate to communicate to cloud. When I try to publish data to a topic I am receiving the following error.
**No handlers could be found for logger "AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.protocol.mqtt_core"**
I have checked the policy for the topic. It has publish permission to the topic and connect permission to all topics.

Comment: Can you include the policy in your question and any relevant code?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B084WZH8G5